# elfinder setting dynamic upload path

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, elfinder

I am using codeigniter, i want to make elfinder upload path to be dynamic for every id.
my folder hierarchy is like this:

[image: client code is dynamic]

my elfinder opts :

```
$idce = $_GET['id_c'];

  $client_code = $this->db->select('client_code')
                        ->get_where('tb_clients', array('id_c' => $idce))
                        ->row()
                        ->client_code;
  $tval = $this->db->select('tanggal_valuasi')
                        ->get_where('tb_clients', array('id_c' => $idce))
                        ->row()
                        ->tanggal_valuasi;

  $opts = array(


    // 'debug' => true,

    'roots' => array(
      array(
        'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem',
        'path' => './upload/'.$client_code.'./proposal/',
        'startPath'  =>'./storage/'.$client_code.'./proposal/',
        'URL' => site_url('storage').'/'.$client_code.'/'.'proposal/',
        'attributes' => array(
          array( // hide readmes
            'pattern' => '/.quarantine'.'/',

            // 'read' => false,
            // 'write' => false,

            'hidden' => true,

            // 'locked' => false

          ) ,
          array( // restrict access to png files
            'pattern' => '/.tmb'.'/',

            // 'read' => false,
            // 'write' => false,

            'hidden' => true,

            // 'locked' => false

          ) 
        ) ,
        'uploadDeny' => array(
          'text/php',
          'text/x-php',
          'application/php',
          'application/x-php',
          'application/x-httpd-php',
          'application/x-httpd-php-source',
          'text/html',
          'text/css',
          'text/js',
          'application/js',
          'application/x-javascript',
          'application/javascript',
          'application/ecmascript',
          'text/javascript',
          'text/ecmascript',
          'application/octet-stream'
        ) ,
        'disabled' => array(
          'rename'
        ) ,
      )
    )
  );
  $this->load->library('elfinder_lib', $opts);
}
```

this is my javascript calling elfinder:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('asset/elfinder/js/elfinder.full.js');?>">
</script>

 <!-- elFinder initialization (REQUIRED) -->
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $().ready(function() {
        var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
            customData : {'id_c': document.getElementById('id_c').value},
            defaultView : 'list',
            url : '<?= base_url(); ?>admin/proposal_contract/elfinder_init',  
    `enter code here`// connector URL (REQUIRED)
            uiOptions: {
                toolbar : [
                    // toolbar configuration
                    ['back', 'forward'],
                    ['reload'],
                    ['home', 'up'],
                    ['upload'],
                    ['open'],
                    ['info'],
                    ['copy', 'cut', 'paste'],

                ]
            }
        }).elfinder('instance');
     });
  </script>
```

the result is elfinder showing the right folder that i want which is under '(client_code)/proposal' folder, but when i try to upload file, the uploaded file is not appear in 'proposal' folder. instead appear in root folder 'mysite/proposal'. so it seems elfinder cannot read my dynamic variable to be path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, finally i can get this straight..
turns out that i just need to add 'requestType : POST', so elfinder can recognize the custom data.

```
<!-- elFinder initialization (REQUIRED) -->
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $().ready(function() {
    var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
        customData : {'id_c': document.getElementById('id_c').value},
        defaultView : 'list',
        requestType : post,
        url : '<?= base_url(); ?>admin/proposal_contract/elfinder_init',  
`enter code here`// connector URL (REQUIRED)
        uiOptions: {
            toolbar : [
                // toolbar configuration
                ['back', 'forward'],
                ['reload'],
                ['home', 'up'],
                ['upload'],
                ['open'],
                ['info'],
                ['copy', 'cut', 'paste'],

            ]
        }
    }).elfinder('instance');
 });
```

The AJAX request type. Available choices are post and get.